# How to convert Uniform normality variables in python?

Tags: python, matlab, normal-distribution, uniform

assign x~U(a,b)
get a uniform distribution array:

```
x_U=uniform(a,b,1000)
```

There is a normality distribution:

```
y~N(μ,σ)
```

I want get array `y_N` which is correspondently related to x_U elements.
How to carry out in python? It looks like easy in matlab. [Such as this link explainnation](https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35281-transforming-uniform-variables-to-normal-variables).
The code as follows is Normality convert to Uniform:

```
from numpy.random import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = normal(25,5.4,1000)
hist_N = plt.hist(a,bins=20,normed=True)
a_cum = np.cumsum(a)
hist_U = plt.hist(a_cum,bins=20,normed=True)
```

## `a_cum` is uniform correspondent related to `a` elements

[image]
[image]

Generating unifrom random number will be applied to Monto-Carlo simulation.But the original parameter is normality distribution.So it needs convertion. My purpose is to inverse above coding process.

Comment: What do you mean "correspondently related to x_U elements"?

Comment: I show an example additionally. It would be clearer.@BrenBarn

Comment: I need to make clear that this is not the right way to create normally distributed random values. What you get is a poor approximation, especially in the tails of the distribution. Correct algorithms to generate normally distributed random values work differently, taking more than one uniformly distributed random value for each normally distributed random value. Both MATLAB and Python have these functions available (see `randn`).

Answer (score 3):

If I follow the link in your question, it tells me what to do. I am not sure that the *erfinv* does, but this code seems to convert a random uniform array to a gaussian shaped array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erfinv

X = np.random.uniform(0,1,1000)
Gauss = lambda x, mu, sigma: mu + np.sqrt(2)*sigma*erfinv(2*x-1)
plt.hist(Gauss(X, 1, 0.2), bins = 20)
plt.show()
```

Gauss is here a function, made with the lambda statement, which basically works the same as defining a function with *def*. The function I used is the one that was in your link.

The gaussian shape looks like
[image: this] and the uniform shape like
[image: this].

Comment: Is erfinv()  inverse function? which is original function? If we know inverse function of Normality, I think the problem is solved.

Comment: I think erfinv is the inverse of the erf function, which is this one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function